# Detecting $(this) parent

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm making a pomodoro clock, i'm trying to detect on where increase button was click, if it's on session-setter then increase the sessionVal else if it's not then alert something (just a test to see if it's being detected), im trying to do this by detecting the .increase (this) parent... The sessionVal increase when i click the .increase button on session-setter , but when i click the .increase button on break-setter the sessionVal increases too instead of alerting error..

My Script

```
$(".increase").on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log($(this).parent().parent()) // this logged .increase parent parent session-setter and break-setter, but when .increase button on break-setter is click sessionVal stills increment instead of alerting error
    if($(this).parent().parent("#session-setter") && onSession){
        sessionVal+=1;
        counter =0;
        $(this).parent().children("#session-value").html(sessionVal);
    }else{ //if another from another parent
        alert("error"); //just a test to see if else is being detected
    }
})
```

My HTML

```
  <div class="control-wrapper">
            <div id="break-setter">
                <h2>Break Length</h2>
                <div class="break-controllers">
                    <button class="decrease">-</button>
                    <span id="break-value">5</span>
                    <button class="increase">+</button>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div id="session-setter">
                <h2>Session Length</h2>
                <div class="session-controllers">
                    <button class="decrease">-</button>
                    <span id="session-value">25</span>
                    <button class="increase">+</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: use .parents() instead and target the id of the parent you trying to catch.

Comment: check $(this).parent().parent("#session-setter") == true not just $(this).parent().parent("#session-setter") and same for session

Comment: Please also use $(this).parents("#session-setter") instead $(this).parent().parent("#session-setter")

Comment: $(this).parent().parent("#session-setter") == true didn't work, $(this).parents("#session-setter") stills increment breakVal

Comment: Make up your mind if you want to use `id` or `class` to identify elements.

Comment: And read http://api.jquery.com/is/

Comment: Your HTML is invalid, it includes duplicate id's. `decrease` 
 also `$(this).parent().children("#session-value").html(sessionVal);` can simply be `$"#session-value").html(sessionVal);` since an ID MUST be unique in a document.
https://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/elements.html#the-id-attribute

Comment: @Tomalak is() is what i needed thanks a lot